# Using stsadm command- SharePoint 2007, How to Get Content DB name through Site collection URL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am having site collection URL and want to find content DB name for it, can anyone please share the stsadm command for this?

Answer (score 0):

stsadm enumsites will return a XML with the content database information among other things.

> stsadm.exe -o enumsites -url virtual_server_URL

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262492(v=office.12).aspx

Sample: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spblog/2009/06/19/stsadm-part-2/